# "Quintessential Example"

Tags: grammar

"The Titanic was a quintessential example of the class system being discriminatory."

Is this the correct use of the word "quintessential"? I wasn't sure if using the phrase "quintessential example" was gramatically correct.

Thank you!

Comment: *was* it? Or is it still?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**quintessential** [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/quintessential)
adj

> most typically representative of a quality, state, etc; perfect

It appears to be correct in grammatical use. Whether is is true is a matter of opinion.